# iPhone photos are low resolution (640x480)

Tags: iphone, photos, resolution

I have an iPhone 4 with which I take lots of photos. The default resolution tends to be pretty high, usually around 2500 X 1900.

Lately some of my photos have come out with a very low resolution, 640x480, rendering them useless for my purpose.  I have not been using HD, nor have I changed any settings. I don't even see an option to change the resolution.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Have you shot any of those images with the "other" camera? The "face time" camera will only shoot a resolution of 640x480 and the "regular" camera shoots the higher resolution (5MP). Apple specs of the iPhone 4 states the face time camera shoots VGA (see http://support.apple.com/kb/sp587).

The high res camera shoots frontward. The face time camera shoots backwards (it is located near the ear speaker in the top of the phone above the screen). When using the camera app, if you press the icon that has the circular arrows, the camera changes to the one facing you (you will see yourself in the screen). That is the "face time" camera and shoots low res.

Comment: Thanks,  this may be the cause however I do not know where the "other" camera is located.  I simply use the camera icon that is on the home screen.  I have OS6.

Comment: @needhelp5097 Chris might be referring to the physical front facing camera as opposed to the rear facing camera. With two physical cameras, it sometimes matters if you are using the landscape/portrait one or the selfie one.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had exactly the same thing happen... All my todays photos were worthless... I found that I must have accidentally turned the flash back to auto. When I changed it back from "auto" to "off" the resolution went back up.